# How to use window.onload in dart?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    const video = document.getElementById("my-video");
    console.log(document.hidden);
    return document.hidden ? video.pause() : video.play();
  });
};
```

Suppose i have this in JS i wish to perform similar action in dart?
[Issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw3KQ.png)
[Function Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciWBT.png)

Comment: Is this dart, or flutter web?

Comment: picture which i shared is in flutter web